# How to building an android application for specific device?

Tags: android, build, device

I developed an android app and i want to give it to testers for test, so i want to make several specific build for each tester, runnable on specific tester device not any devices.

the reason is when i give a build of my app to a tester, the app just be runnable on his device not others, so can not be published and run on any other devices!

***How can you guarantee that a tester don't publish your app?!***

Comment: You can set a sort of `timed bomb` in your app so it won't run after a given date. By this, you won't need to worry about your app getting published or distributed by others.

Comment: You want DRM, which isn't a trivial fix and cannot be described in a few lines of code on StackExchange.  The easiest solution to your problem is to find trustworthy testers since it's simple enough to decompile your byte code, strip out any protection you might jury-rig on your own and publish the code anyhow.  In short, you cannot guarantee that a tester doesn't publish your app.

Answer (score 0):

You're speaking of a particular model of device, as opposed to a specific handset, like the Samsung Galaxy 3 I have in my pocket or the Nexus 7 on my desk, as distinguished from all other Samsung Galaxy 3 and Nexus 7 devices, yes?

Try using:

```
android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

in your activity.  This field will give you the model number of the phone, and you can just branch to either run or not run your code if it's the wrong model of phone.

Comment: Thanks MarsAtomic, But I want specific device not specific model!

Answer (score 0):

to do this you can get the IMEI number of the device from that tester and in your application check the IMEI number.

It certainly has a limitations. it will need gsm handsets only ( you can use mac addess instead).

To get the IMEI of a device

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String IMEI = manager.getDeviceId()
```

you will need the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission

Answer (score 0):

you can do following

- Use device Android Id
- Use Mac Address

All these expected to be unique for every device.

So every time you app run, you check for those number and match.